# Possible to call a function to all particular objects stored in project environment?

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, environment

I, stupidly, have been creating loads of new data_frames in an R project trying to solve a particular problem without making proper commits. Having gone through all practical names and most of the Greek alphabet, I now have an environment full of data_frame objects with names like 'bob','might.work','almostthere'.  I'd like to use a looping function - lapply or otherwise - to return some indicators that will tell me something about each dataframe object in the environment.  I can then clean up/delete based on the returns.

So is it possible to use lapply to access all data_frames in an R project environment? Something like this?

```
lapply(environment, function (x){
  if(is.dataframe(x)){
  dplyr::glimpse(x)
}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eapply()` function easily iterates over objects in an environment

```
eapply(globalenv(), function(x) if (is.data.frame(x)) dplyr::glimpse(x))
```

Comment: Wow!, This is perfect! Thanks, and to think, I was only one letter off.

Answer (score 1):

Sure is possible!

```
lapply(ls(),function(x){
  o = get(x,envir = globalenv())
  cat("if"(is.data.frame(o),paste0(x," is a data frame!\n"),"Nope.\n"))
})
```

- `ls()` will list all object names in the environment (global by default).
- Since this is just a name, we need to `get` the value but specify the global environment (since we're in a function environment at this point)
- Then I `cat` out if it's a data frame, but you can do whatever you want with the `o` object.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return the objects that inherit from class `data.frame` in the environment `environ`, which defaults to `.GlobalEnv`.

```
getDataFrames <- function(environ = .GlobalEnv){
    l <- ls(name = environ)
    res <- NULL
    for(i in seq_along(l)){
        r <- inherits(get(l[i], envir = environ), "data.frame")
        if(r) res <- c(res, l[i])
    }
    res
}

getDataFrames()
```