# Applying a function to all data.frames in the environment

Tags: r, function, for-loop, lapply

I would like to use the `cleanfunction` below on all data.frames in my environment.

```
cleanfunction <- function(dataframe) {
  dataframe <- as.data.frame(dataframe)
  ## get mode of all vars
  var_mode <- sapply(dataframe, mode)
  ## produce error if complex or raw is found
  if (any(var_mode %in% c("complex", "raw"))) stop("complex or raw not allowed!")
  ## get class of all vars
  var_class <- sapply(dataframe, class)
  ## produce error if an "AsIs" object has "logical" or "character" mode
  if (any(var_mode[var_class == "AsIs"] %in% c("logical", "character"))) {
      stop("matrix variables with 'AsIs' class must be 'numeric'")
      }
  ## identify columns that needs be coerced to factors
  ind1 <- which(var_mode %in% c("logical", "character"))
  ## coerce logical / character to factor with `as.factor`
  dataframe[ind1] <- lapply(dataframe[ind1], as.factor)
  return(dataframe)
}

set.seed(10238)
DT = data.table(
  A = rep(1:3, each = 5L), 
  B = rep(1:5, 3L),
  C = sample(15L),
  D = sample(15L)
)
DT_II <- copy(DT)
dfs <- ls()
```

Now I want to apply this function to all df's in the enviroment. I have tried like ten things, but I cannot get the syntax rigtht..

```
for (i in seq_along(dfs)) {
  get(dfs[i])[ , lapply(.SD, cleanfunction)]
}
```

## EDIT:

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421990/possible-to-call-a-function-to-all-particular-objects-stored-in-project-environm), but it does not store the result.

```
eapply(globalenv(), function(x) if (is.data.frame(x)) cleanfunction(x))
```

How do I store the result in each object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `get(dfs[i])` which returns a reference to a `data.table`, but then you are `lapply`-ing each column of that frame and I'm inferring from the function argument `dataframe` that you expect a full frame. One might start with:

```r
for (i in seq_along(dfs)) {
  get(dfs[i])[ , cleanfunction(.SD)]
}
```

but realize that this operation returns a new frame, it does not use canonical `data.table` mechanisms for updating data in-place. I suggest you update your function to always force `data.table` and work on it referentially.

```r
cleanfunction <- function(dataframe) {
  setDT(dataframe)
  ## get mode of all vars
  var_mode <- sapply(dataframe, mode)
  ## produce error if complex or raw is found
  if (any(var_mode %in% c("complex", "raw"))) stop("complex or raw not allowed!")
  ## get class of all vars
  var_class <- sapply(dataframe, class)
  ## produce error if an "AsIs" object has "logical" or "character" mode
  if (any(var_mode[var_class == "AsIs"] %in% c("logical", "character"))) {
      stop("matrix variables with 'AsIs' class must be 'numeric'")
      }
  ## identify columns that needs be coerced to factors
  ind1 <- which(var_mode %in% c("logical", "character"))
  ## coerce logical / character to factor with `as.factor`
  if (length(ind1)) dataframe[, c(ind1) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = ind1]
  return(dataframe)
}
```

Since your current data does not trigger any changes, I'll update one:

```r
DT[,quux:="A"]
head(DT)
#        A     B     C     D   quux
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <char>
# 1:     1     1    12    15      A
# 2:     1     2     4     6      A
# 3:     1     3     5     7      A
# 4:     1     4     9     1      A
# 5:     1     5     6    14      A
# 6:     2     1    15    13      A

for (i in seq_along(dfs)) cleanfunction(get(dfs[i]))
head(DT)
#        A     B     C     D   quux
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <fctr>
# 1:     1     1    12    15      A
# 2:     1     2     4     6      A
# 3:     1     3     5     7      A
# 4:     1     4     9     1      A
# 5:     1     5     6    14      A
# 6:     2     1    15    13      A
```

Note that the `for` loop is relying solely on referential updates; the return value from `cleanfunction` is ignored here.

This method works *entirely* because of `data.table` referential semantics; if you were using `data.frame` or `tbl_df`, this would likely require wrapping that call to `cleanfunction(.)` with `assign(dfs[i], cleanfunction(..))`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?:

```
# store all dataframes from environment a list
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

#then apply your function
lapply(dfs, cleanfunction)
```